# What class am I most prepared for?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, soft-question, euclidean-geometry

I've only taken up to calc 3, discrete, and linear algebra. Which course am I most prepared for?
I'm going to be taking differential equations and advanced calc, but I want to take a 3rd class. I can choose from combinatorics, elementary number theory, and euclidean/noneuclidean geometry. Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: The "correct" answer depends on several considerations. Is "preparedness" really the best criterion? What are your goals? Why are you taking these math courses? What do you hope to learn and why?

Comment: Talk to your advisor!

Comment: +1 for jdc's comment. You will also want to consider the level of rigor expected in the courses and how much proof is required. How much, if any, proof background did your discrete and linear algebra courses provide?

Comment: well I eventually want to go into teaching. Since I'm obviously new to upper level math courses though, I haven't really found what I like. So I'm just trying to branch out but also make sure I don't take anything I'm not prepared for (because I know pre-req classes are hardly accurate for preparedness)

Answer (score 1):

If Advanced Calculus is your introductory analysis course, that's a tough one. I personally am not an analyst and favor combinatorics/graph theory instead. I find them to be at the opposite ends of the spectrum. Elementary Number Theory going to start off probably very familiar, if you've seen divisibility proofs, modular arithmetic, and the Euclidean Algorithm. You get into topics like quadratic residues, the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and a bit into the discrete log problem. I think Number Theory is probably the easiest out of the three. I'm not a geometer, so I'd personally avoid geometry.

If you're pursuing a Discrete Math or Computer Science track, I'd go for Combinatorics or Number Theory.

This is probably more comment material, but the post is too long. Hope this helps some!

Comment: yeah advanced calc would be my intro analysis course. I personally am on a teaching track, but I have liked the little bit of number theory we've done in discrete. I don't want an easy A, I just don't want to get into a class that I am nowhere near prepared for.

Comment: Advanced Calc will get you thinking at a lower and more meticulous level. Combinatorics is a train your brain course. Taking the two of them together and going in opposite directions is a lot. If your combinatorics course includes graph theory, that's a plus in terms of teaching. Graph theory is a field where you can explain the problems to a smart 3rd grader, but they have a lot of depth to them. The counting aspect of combinatorics is really tough. Number Theory is probably easier to incorporate into a secondary education curriculum than graph theory.

Comment: I think you would be prepared for both Number Theory and Combinatorics, but there is something to be said for not overloading. I took Combinatorics at my school (2/3 graph theory, 1/3 counting) and it pushed me, but I benefited from it far more in terms of the "train your brain" aspect than with number theory.